# Laravel - Jquery data-repeater-item binding to a report tab

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to bind data from jQuery data-repeater-item to a report tabs, when we click on create a new item, I want to add a new row in the report with all data from the repeater item.

So far, I've only managed to bind 1 item in the report instead of Y item.
(Y is the number of time that we repeate the list.)

I think that I will need a foreach loop but i don't know how to do

For now, my code look like this :

```
<div data-repeater-item class="row">
    <select class="form-control" name="position">
        <option value="Front right">Front right</option>
        <option value="Front left">Front left</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

When I check my report in the Tabs4, I  display the value of the position using jQuery

Html from using a blade template for loop

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 sbold">Tyre Position:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="form-control-static" data-display="tyre[{{ $number }}][position]"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Js

```
$('#tab3, .form-control-static', form).each(function () {

    var input = $('[name="' + $(this).attr("data-display") + '"]', form);

    if (input.is(":radio")) {
        input = $('[name="' + $(this).attr("data-display") + '"]:checked', form);
    }

    if (input.is(":text") || input.is("textarea")) {
        $(this).html(input.val().replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
    } else if (input.is("select")) {
        $(this).html(input.find('option:selected').text());
    } else if (input.is(":radio") && input.is(":checked")) {
        $(this).html(input.attr("data-title"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this solution is the best but it does the thing I want with a jQuery click action on the button repeater.

When I click on the button Repeater, I will inject html with the append() method from Jquery

```
  $('.injection').click(function() {
```

> var inject = $('.tyreinjection');

```
for (var number=1; number < 5; ++number) {

  inject.append('<div  class="row">');
    inject.append('<p class="form-control-static" data-display="tyre['+number+'][position]"> </p>'); } });
```

For now, this code will create 4 other paragraph that will display the position in the report.